# How do I install Traefik on EKS using Helm but with an ALB instead of an ELB?

Tags: kubernetes, traefik, aws-application-load-balancer

I am trying to install Traefik as my router on EKS. If I do it normally like this, Traefik is installed and fronted by an ELB:

```
helm install traefik traefik/traefik
```

However, I want Traefik to be fronted by an ALB instead so I can have multiple SSL certs attached to it.
I have followed the [EKS workshop guide](https://www.eksworkshop.com/beginner/130_exposing-service/ingress_controller_alb/) to install the aws-load-balancer-controller on my cluster. This has been successful as I could successfully launch the test game and get an ALB. I tried to install Traefik and get an ALB but I don't seem to be able to. Here is how I have tried:

```
helm install traefik traefik/traefik --values values.yaml  --set="additionalArguments={--log.level=DEBUG}"
```

Here is the contents of my values.yaml with the ingress annotations:

```
raynard@Raynards-MacBook-Pro traefik % cat values.yaml                                                                                           
# Use ingressClass. Ignored if Traefik version < 2.3 / kubernetes < 1.18.x
ingressClass:
  # true is not unit-testable yet, pending https://github.com/rancher/helm-unittest/pull/12
  enabled: true
  isDefaultClass: false
  # Use to force a networking.k8s.io API Version for certain CI/CD applications. E.g. "v1beta1"
  fallbackApiVersion: ""

# Create an IngressRoute for the dashboard
ingressRoute:
  dashboard:
    enabled: true
    # Additional ingressRoute annotations (e.g. for kubernetes.io/ingress.class)
    annotations:
      kubernetes.io/ingress.class: alb
      alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/scheme: internet-facing
      alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/target-type: ip
    # Additional ingressRoute labels (e.g. for filtering IngressRoute by custom labels)
    labels: {}
```

When I check, no ingress has been created. However, a svc has been created. again with an ELB:

```
raynard@Raynards-MacBook-Pro traefik % kubectl get ingress
NAME         CLASS    HOSTS                                                                   ADDRESS   PORTS   AGE
infinyprod   <none>   prod.infiny.cloud,cloudlx.epsilontel.com,k83.infiny.cloud + 7 more...             80      69d
raynard@Raynards-MacBook-Pro traefik % kubectl get svc    
NAME                        TYPE           CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP                                                               PORT(S)                      AGE
kubernetes                  ClusterIP      172.20.0.1       <none>                                                                    443/TCP                      150d
my-release-redis-headless   ClusterIP      None             <none>                                                                    6379/TCP                     12d
my-release-redis-master     ClusterIP      172.20.122.33    <none>                                                                    6379/TCP                     12d
my-release-redis-replicas   ClusterIP      172.20.202.106   <none>                                                                    6379/TCP                     12d
traefik                     LoadBalancer   172.20.240.72    a67bbaa57465c438ab0bce03933682e8-1307117939.eu-west-1.elb.amazonaws.com   80:31899/TCP,443:31306/TCP   8m14s
```

Any idea where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you might want to try making the traefik service installed as a NodePort as opposed to the default (LoadBalancer in this case). After that you can then use an ingress pointing to that service.

In your values.yaml file, add:

```
service:
  annotations: {}
  type: NodePort
```

Then make an ingress.yml with the following:

```
---
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  namespace: traefik
  name: traefik-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: alb
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/scheme: internet-facing
spec:
  rules:
    - http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: traefik
                port:
                  number: 80
```